# argument-passing from iOS to WCF service

Tags: objective-c, wcf, argument-passing

I need to pass information from the application to the server, specifically a and b in text format. Here is the code the WCF service:

```
public class iOSService 
{
// To use HTTP GET, add [WebGet] attribute. (Default ResponseFormat is WebMessageFormat.Json)
// To create an operation that returns XML,
// add [WebGet(ResponseFormat=WebMessageFo rmat.Xml)],
// and include the following line in the operation body:
// WebOperationContext.Current.Outgoin gResponse.ContentType = "text/xml";
[OperationContract]
public void DoWork()
{
// Add your operation implementation here
return;
}

// Add more operations here and mark them with [OperationContract]


[OperationContract]
public string iOSTest2(string a, string b)
{
string res = "";
try
{
res=(int.Parse(a) + int.Parse(b)).ToString();
}
catch (Exception exp)
{
res = "Not a number";
}
return res;
}


}
```

After receiving a and b, the server adds them, and sends back their sum.

And here is my code to send parameters to the server of an iOS application:

```
- (IBAction)test:(id)sender {

    NSArray *propertyNames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"23", @"342", nil];
    NSArray *propertyValues = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"a", @"b",  nil];

    NSDictionary *properties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:propertyNames forKeys:propertyValues];

    NSMutableArray  * arr;

    arr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:properties, nil];
    NSLog(@"%@",arr);

    NSError * error;
    NSData *jsonData2 = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:arr options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mathforyou.net/iOSservice.svc/iOSTest2"]];
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData2 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [request setValue:@"appliction/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:jsonData2];
    NSLog(@"JSON String: %@",jsonString);
    NSError *errorReturned = nil;
    NSURLResponse *theResponse =[[NSURLResponse alloc]init];
    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&theResponse error:&errorReturned];
    if (errorReturned) {
        //...handle the error
        NSLog(@"error");
    }
    else {
        NSString *retVal = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSLog(@"%@",retVal);
    }
}
```

But the server answers me the following message:

```
"ExceptionDetail":null,"ExceptionType":null,"Message":"The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the <serviceDebug> configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.","StackTrace":null
```

And here is the logs from Xcode:

```
2013-03-01 17:38:28.657 2231233122[3442:c07] (
        {
        a = 23;
        b = 342;
    }
)
2013-03-01 17:38:28.659 2231233122[3442:c07] JSON String: [
  {
    "a" : "23",
    "b" : "342"
  }
]
2013-03-01 17:38:29.054 2231233122[3442:c07] {"ExceptionDetail":null,"ExceptionType":null,"Message":"The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the <serviceDebug> configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.","StackTrace":null}
```

**P.S.** I asked a friend to help me, but since he does not know objective-c wrote a program just for C++ and the code works, so the problem is not in the server. Here is the code:

```
string data = "{\"a\":\"560\",\"b\":\"90\"}";

byte[] bd = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);

HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.mathforyou.net/IOSService.svc/iOSTest2");
wr.ContentType = "application/json";
wr.Method = "POST";
wr.ContentLength = bd.Length;
Stream sw = wr.GetRequestStream();
sw.Write(bd, 0, bd.Length);
sw.Close();
HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)wr.GetResponse();
Stream s = resp.GetResponseStream();
byte[] bres = new byte[resp.ContentLength];
s.Read(bres, 0, bres.Length);
string ans = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bres);
Console.WriteLine(ans);
```

Please help, I'm worn out.

Comment: Well, I'd start with turning on `IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults` like it recommends so you can see the actual error that is occurring.

Comment: If you know the server code isn't the problem, why did you include it?

Comment: @JoshCaswell Just so you know in what format should pass arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you copied and pasted the code, it looks like you might have misspelled your `Content-Type` value. It should be `application/json`, you have it as `appliction/json`.

Also, I'm not sure if this matters, but you're also not setting the content length explicitly. I am not sure if `setHTTPBody:` does that for you.

Comment: And how do I get the length, and add it to the query?

Comment: I added  NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [jsonData2 length]];
    [request addValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
 but unsuccessfully

Comment: Did you correct your typo for the `Content-Type`? Also, be sure to enable the extra exception details so you can let us know what the error is.

Comment: The program, which was written by my friend and such type of costs, and it all works. (The code is written in question)

Comment: Right, the code in **C#** works, but your Objective-C code does not. In your Objective-C code, your Content-Type value is spelled incorrectly: `[request setValue:@"appliction/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];`.

Comment: Well, without getting the additional exception details, we can't really help much more.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you still need this, but try the following:

```
[request addValue:@"application/json; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:jsonString forHTTPHeaderField:@"json"]; //<-- I added this line
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:jsonData2];
```